# Nodejs get mysql insertId and handle errors

Tags: javascript, node.js

i want to simply handle error and get insertId after created new row on database, in my code which i get help from `mysqljs/mysql` official page, i can't do them, how can i fix my code to do them?

```
var post = {deviceImei: deviceInformation.deviceImei, created_at: currentDateTime, updated_at: currentDateTime};
var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', post, function (err, result) {
    if (err)
        throw err;
    return result;
});
query.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log(err)
}).on('fields', function (fields) {
    console.log(fields)
}).on('result', function (row) {
    console.log(row.insertId);
}).on('end', function () {
    // all rows have been received
});
```

after insert or get some error i cant any message on shell by console

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do that is [documented here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#getting-the-id-of-an-inserted-row):

```
connection.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', post, function(err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log(result.insertId);
});
```

Comment: Then i have to put all other functions into that. And i dont like it.how can i get result out of `connection` ?

Comment: @Mahdi.Pishguy - You should follow this example...You can promise it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use native ES6 promises supported in newest versions of node

```
var insertQuery = function(post) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        connection.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', post, function (err, result) {
            if (err)
                reject(error);
            resolve(result);
        }
    });
}
```

The you can handle after

```
insertQuery(post)
    .then(function(result) {
        console.log(result.inserId);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(err);
    })
```

There are libs like 'q' or 'bluebird' which are easy to use too